# GetKeyState doesn't register if holding ctrl

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

Given this statement:

```
if (GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 0x8000)
{
    cout << "caps lock" << endl;
}
```

It works fine if I press caps lock alone, or along with any key **except** ctrl. I was thinking it's because ctrl is a modifier, but this works fine when holding shift. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GetKeyState() provides the *synchronized* state of the keyboard.  The state of all the keys when the key was pressed.  It can take a while before your program sees it, Windows provides type-ahead, so it is important that the state of all keys is known to reliably detect whether Shift, Alt, Ctrl were down at the time.

The synchronized state gets updated when you call GetMessage(). Done in the boilerplate message loop of a Windows program.

But since you use `cout`, you probably wrote a console mode program and don't use a message loop at all.  So it doesn't update.  And you'll have to use GetAsyncKeyState().  No buffering at all, so you have to call it often.  Do note that the console also has a way to [retrieve keystrokes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684961(v=vs.85).aspx) with buffering supported.  Probably what you really want/should do when you write code like this.  Watch out for input redirection.

Comment: This happens in a loop as well, without a console (using a renderer to test)

Comment: If it is a "loop" then it probably isn't calling Get/PeekMessage().  So same problem.  The SDK has a [silly example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644928(v=vs.85).aspx), DoLengthyOperation() code.  Just guessing at this, the snippet in the question is too brief to know what you are doing and why.